# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executeScript') for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a chrome extension that worked perfectly up until a few weeks ago. Now when I run it, I get this error. This wasn't present before. I'm unsure as to why it's not working considering I have all the needed permissions in my JSON. Can anyone provide help?

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executeScript')
```

```
Background.js
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function (selection) {
  const selectedText = selection[0];
  const resultSentence = removeStopWords(selectedText);
  document.getElementById("new-task").innerHTML = resultSentence;
```

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": ""
  "version": "",
  "description": "",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "tabs",
    "storage"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Good question. According to the linked question, you can't use `chrome.tabs` in content scripts, but you should be able to use it in background scripts and service workers.

Comment: Yes, I should've specified. I made sure this is in my background script, not my content script.

Comment: That's clear from `"service_worker": "background.js"`

Comment: Yes, so why am I getting an error if it's in my background script?

Comment: Like I said above: Good question! I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Yeah I've done much research on this error and can't seem to find any solution. I guess I could find an alternative to using chrome.tabs but I don't know of any that work. When I use just the window.getselection without the chrome, it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: if it was running, and isn't running now, and you've made no changes, that suggests a recent Chrome update broke something. This isn't at all unsurprising as every major release of Chrome manages to break something - see if Chrome has a (minor?) update available

Comment: This solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542700/getting-selected-text-in-a-chrome-extension

Comment: In ManifestV3 executeScript is in a different namespace: `chrome.scripting`.